# Find transform rotation value of Ground Plane in Vuforia for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I would like to find out the Quaternian values for the rotataion of a placed game-object using Ground Plane detection in Vuforia for Unity. When testing in Unity inspector, neither the values for the placed object nor the ground plane hold any live data within the Transform fields. I realise this is only a simulated AR (I am using a webcam and Ground Plane trigger print out). But, I would expect nonetheless to be able to access the rotation (and idealy the Z index of the position of the game-object). I suspect this data is stored internally within the Vuforia object management. Howevern I have been unable to find any reference from within the Vuforia docs.

How do I retreive the rotational value of the ground place and/or placed game-object (anchor)?

Comment: the AR Camera is rotating around object, you should check that.

Comment: The question related to Ground Plane detection not object detection. I need to know the rotation of the "game-object" which is placed on the ground plane. Usually one would expect to access this info via the game-object's Transform property. However, this is not the case with Vuforia.